# How can I add class based on hidden field value?

Tags: jquery

I have set a model value inside hidden field,

```html
 <input type="hidden" value="@Model.textServiceType" id="hdtextListServiceType" />
```

Then I am binding `a` element by using `foreach` loop,

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="main-sectors">
            @foreach (var item in Model.listServiceType)
            {
                <a href="#" class="p-l-35">@Html.Raw(item)s</a>
            }
            <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Products</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to add `sector-active` class which `hdtextListServiceType` value equal. I have tried this code. But not happening.

```js
 if ($('#hdtextListServiceType').val() != "") {
       
        $('a').removeClass('sector-active');

        if($('.main-sectors a').html() == $('#hdtextListServiceType').val() ){          
            $('.main-sectors a').addClass('sector-active');
        }
          
    }
```

How can I do this ? please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.each() to iterate over anchor tag. Below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#hdtextListServiceType').val() != "") {
    $('a').removeClass('sector-active');
      $('.main-sectors a').each(function(){
        if($(this).html()==$('#hdtextListServiceType').val()){
        $(this).addClass('sector-active');
      }
    });
  }
});
```